# Cannot Install New Software (Store Bug)

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

When I try to install new software, the `dpkg` and the `libllvm12` interrupts the process with the following errors:

```
 The following packages have mismatched dependencies: 
libllvm12 : Break: libllvm12:i386 (!= 1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.3) but 1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.4 is installed  libllvm12:i386 : Break: libllvm12 (!= 1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.4) but 1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.3 is installed 
E: Mismatched dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' without any packages (or specify a solution)
```

Also `sudo apt --fix-broken install` doesn't work because `dpkg` comes with an error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompression> returned exit status 2 
error dpkg: error processing file /var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm12_1%3a12.0.0-3 ubuntu1~20.04.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
cannot copy extracted data to './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so. 1' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1.dpkg-new': 
end of file or  unexpected stream 
Errors were encountered while processing:  
/var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm12_1%3a12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.4_amd64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also, The Ubuntu store is broken, text only, gear icon, and screenshots cannot be found.

Comment: If you still have the USB, you should be able to reinstall the packages without DPKG. If you can access the Software & Updates menu, you can select the Ubuntu installer to reinstall. Or you can download the files from the internet and unpack/reinstall them manually.

Comment: Did you have disk space available to perform these operations? try `$ sudo apt-get autoclean` `$ sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: The description seems more like mis-configured sources or some other user-created issue rather than a real bug. But the description is vague, so it might be after all. Edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` Additional detail on what might have happened to cause those problems would get you good advice much faster. If we must speculate, fewer volunteers will be willing to help.